# Adobe After Effects free and open-source alternative

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I used to work on Adobe After Effects at a studio that had a license for it. I learned it and could use it for my own projects, but I will never have the money to purchase it. I most definitely do not want to obtain it illegaly as some people do. I would like to use something similar, without such high costs, when freelancing.

So the question:

- is there an Adobe After Effects "clone" available in the free / open-source world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to look for open source alternatives is [Osalt](http://www.osalt.com/after-effects). They suggest [Jahshaka](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jahshakafx/) as a replacement for Adobe After Effects.

That being said what you're asking is awfully close to a request for a product endorsement.